# Is there an equivalent of TeX's \hfill in CSS?

Tags: css

Subject says it all. I know that I can use `float:left` and `float:right`, but this does not work if the combined lenght of texts is more than a line. I would like to have some text anchored to the left and some other text anchored to the right, but I don't know in advance how much text there is.

Comment: `float` works with a single line as well with multiple, see https://jsfiddle.net/zxrmfv31/

Comment: @OlafDietsche it works because you have a short width for both columns. I must mimic something like https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/63/Goldoni_-_Opere_complete%2C_Tomo_I%2C_Venezia_1907%2C_I.djvu/page598-1024px-Goldoni_-_Opere_complete%2C_Tomo_I%2C_Venezia_1907%2C_I.djvu.jpg

Comment: I cannot see the image, do you mean https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=File%3AGoldoni_-_Opere_complete%2C_Tomo_I%2C_Venezia_1907%2C_I.djvu&page=598? This is done with a `<table>`.

Comment: @OlafDietsche no - look at https://imgur.com/a/FBIRCSl . As you may see, for example ''(bruscamente'' is right justified within the line.